# ssh-copy-id equivalent for giving a client a key for a server?

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-copy-id

I’m currently delving more into homeserver activities, and I was wondering if there was a way to add a client to my server’s list of allowed keys for SSH. I currently have SSH set up to use PublickeyAuthentication in my sshd_config, and I feel like having to turn this setting off every time I want to add a new client to SSH from is insecure. Is there a serverside command I should be using for this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent *on a server* would be to just add the public key to the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file in whichever way you like. There's no dedicated command for doing so.

For example, you could carry your new client computer's id_rsa.pub to the server on a USB stick, or relay it via 'scp' or 'sftp' through an already-trusted computer, or manually type it in, or use a hardware-protected portable key such as a Yubikey for the initial connection. (There are probably 10 more different methods to do it.)

ssh-copy-id basically just does:

1. uploads id_rsa.pub using `scp`;
2. appends it using `cat your_uploaded_key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the server.